# Identify this cactus I received as a gift

Tags: identification, cactus

I got this cactus as a gift. Please help me identify it.

It's pretty weird. It's like they've glued some glitter on a plant :)

[image]
[image]

Here's a photo of a dead leaf:

[image]
[image]

edit:

I was able to peel off the covering of two of the leaves:

[image]
[image]

Comment: That kinds of looks like a jade plant that someone put "flocking" on (I'm defining flocking here as a sticky powder sprayed onto a plant for decorative purposes. In the US, this is sometimes done on Christmas trees to mimic snow on the branches). Does the powder (if it IS powder) come off of a leaf when you rub it kind of vigorously? Is so, what does the leave look like without the powder? If not, and based on the final photo, it kind of looks like the coating may have formed a shell over the leaf? Could this be possible? If so, then the plant may not be salvageable.

Comment: @Jurp yeah, it does kinda look like a jade plant.
I was able to remove some of the flocking and added two pictures in the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kinds of looks like a jade plant that someone put "flocking" on (I'm defining flocking here as a sticky powder sprayed onto a plant for decorative purposes. In the US, this is sometimes done on Christmas trees to mimic snow on the branches). Because you were able to remove some of the flocking, I'd suggest that if you want to save the plant you should remove as much of it as possible.

If you start at the top of one of the branches, you could remove it from perhaps the top 5-8cm of leaves (if it's even that tall), then remove the rest of the leaves, make a cutting of this piece, and plant the cutting in a pot full of decent potting soil.

Answer (score 2):

There actually are succulents with fuzzy leaves that look like that. It seems unusual that you can peel the fuzz off all at once like this, so I'm undecided whether you have a naturally fuzzy succulent or one that someone sprayed a fuzzy coating onto. It seems like a very weird thing to do to a living plant, but I suppose it might be cheaper to use a live plant than manufacture one out of plastic. If you have more than one stem, you could try peeling the fuzz off of all the leaves on one stem, and see if that stem survives and puts out new growth.

Here are some similar naturally fuzzy succulent plants:

[Echeveria pulvinata 'Frosty'](https://mountaincrestgardens.com/echeveria-pulvinata-frosty/)

[image]

[Kalenchoe tomentosa / Panda Plant](https://mountaincrestgardens.com/kalanchoe-tomentosa-panda-plant/)

[image]

[Crassula pubescens](https://worstroom.com/types-of-jade-plants/) (scroll down to number 14 on the linked page) - the leaves actually start out green and turn red as they mature, but can stay green if not exposed to enough sunlight

[image]